# SQLAlchemy JSON column custom properties

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy JSON columns can contain arbitrary datastructures. To have easier access to some of the deeper elements of the column, I'd like to create custom properties on the column. A simple example can be a column like:

```py
class Model(db.Model):
    language = db.Column(postgresql.JSON(), nullable=False,
                         default={"nl": "", "en": ""})
```

Then I'd like to have an property on the `language` attribute such that we can type `entity.language.en` and `entity.language.nl`. I've attempted to create a custom column type:

```py
class TranslatedColumn(db.Column):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(postgresql.JSON(), nullable=False,
                         default={"nl": "", "en": ""})
    @hybrid_property
    def en(self):
        return self["en"].astext
    @hybrid_property
    def nl(self):
        return self["nl"].astext
```

Which works when querying the column: `db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.language.en == "somestr")...`, however when I try to access the column on an entity, `entity.language == {"nl": "", "en": ""}`, which is a `dict`.

Is there any way to create a such a structure, based on the JSON columns of SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I think you might get close with a `TypeDecorator`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types